# Android: Arrayoutofindexbounds with Thread

Tags: android, arrays, multithreading, indexing, bounds

I have a little problem with my code. I keep getting an `arrayoutofindexbounds` with the following code:

```
    public boolean checksouth(int r,int c, int numofwords) {
    if (south==false)
    {return false;}
    computer_find=0;

    for (int x=0;x<=(numofwords-1);x++)
    {
        if (worduniverse[(r-x)][c]==computer_words[x])   **bold**<=Problem arises here>
        {
        computer_find++;
        }
    }

    if ((computer_find==numofwords)&&(numofwords!=0))
    {
        r_computer=r;
        c_computer=c;
        direction_computer=2;
        highlight_num=numofwords;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

My objective is to create a Word search protocol that would not use the UI. When I put the code into the UI the system kept giving me an `ANR`.

However the code, while in UI, never gave me an `Arrayoutofindex`. The `arrayoutofindex` only occurs once the code is called from another thread. I cannot understand this. Any help would be appreciated.

I must point out that the code accurately worked outside the Thread. When it was put into another thread it gave me false results. I need the thread in order to reduce possibility of ANR in my app.

The `Logcat` output simply points to the location I have highlighted.

Comment: Try putting a conditional breakpoint on that line and examining your variables and call stack when the values are such that an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is going to be thrown. Is one thread modifying some of these variables while another is calling the method? Perhaps you need some synchronization to gain exclusive use of the values while the method executes.

Comment: try to use synchronize in your method....

Comment: try to print value of x before the comparison... i think problem is because of the x being higher than numofwords ... which is possible while using threads..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AsyncTask insted : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I like to thank all for the help. I achieved my objective by simply including all code into one method. Was a lot faster and did not give me an ANR.

I was always getting an ANR because I had multiple methods to help me do brute force word alogrithnm. Weedled the methods down to one and the search took less than 1.5 seconds on an Android phone.